# Problem with inserting from one table to another!

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
    StringBuilder insertCommand = new StringBuilder();

    insertCommand.Append("DECLARE @TopicsId int; INSERT INTO Topics(Theme,Topics,Date)");
    insertCommand.Append("VALUES(@topic,@subTopic,GETDATE())");
    insertCommand.Append("SET @TopicsId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()");

    insertCommand.Append("INSERT INTO Threads(UsersID,TopicsID,Date,ThreadTitle,ThreadParagraph,ThreadClosed,Views,Replies,PageNumber)");
    insertCommand.Append(" SELECT u.UsersID,@TopicsID,GETDATE(),@questionTitle,@questionParagraph,0,0,0,FLOOR(Count(t.TopicsID)/20)"); // i think the problem is in the u.UserID in this line
    insertCommand.Append(" FROM Threads AS d ");
    insertCommand.Append(" INNER JOIN Topics AS t ON d.TopicsID=t.TopicsID");
    insertCommand.Append(" INNER JOIN Users AS u ON u.UsersID=t.UsersID");
```

I want to insert from Users table UsersID to Threads table. But an exception is thrown saying that there is no such column called as UsersID. I think that it does take u.UserID as a parameter and puts it into Threads UsersID, cause i do have a column in Threads named usersID. is there a solution?

Comment: Why did you include the first three insertCommand.Append lines?  Are these in any way related to the subsequent five lines?  Where are e.g. `@questionTitle` coming from?

Comment: They work fine.. questionTitle comes from the threads table, i feed into it what the user wants

Comment: Based on the `INSERT INTO Topics` statement I would presume you don't have any `Topics.UsersID` column. Possibly, `t.UsersID` should be `d.UsersID`.

Comment: I do, it was the mistake a mistake in the uniqueuserIdentifier.-- i changed the algorithm. now it works. thanks anyway..

Comment: Just a thought - shouldn't you have a semicolon at the end of your fir st INSERT statement, and then one after the SET statement?

Comment: @Will: They are not obligatory in most cases (not in SQL Server, anyway). I tend to put them everywhere for clarity, though.

Comment: @Andriy - thanks for clearing that up, I don't typically use multiple SQL statements through SqlCommands, so it _was_ a shot in the dark!

Comment: @Matrix001: If the problem is solved, please either edit your question to add the notice or, if you can describe your solution, post an answer.

Comment: @Marix001 as this question is related to SQL then it is better to omit your C# code and just paste SQL code... it will really help !!!

Answer (score 0):

have you misspelled a column (UsersID vs UserID)?

if you have direct access to database (i.e. via SQL Management Studio) try running just the select and format your SQL properly so it shows you the problematic row number, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  u.UsersID,@TopicsID,GETDATE(),@questionTitle,@questionParagraph,0,0,0,FLOOR(Count(t.TopicsID)/20))
FROM 
  Threads AS d
INNER JOIN 
  Topics AS t ON d.TopicsID=t.TopicsID
INNER JOIN 
  Users AS u ON u.UsersID=t.UsersID
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Insert into threads(....)
Values (blablabla,blablabla)
```

`INSERT` requires the `VALUES` keyword

I don't see it in the statement

Comment: Actually that's not true.  An insert statement with a nested select works just fine without the values keyword.  Check out http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlinsert.html

Comment: why do i get that exception?..why it doesnt see that i have UsersID